# Famous phrase for something which is forbidden or impossible, but can be done if desired enough

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

In some languages (for example Russian) there is a very famous phrase about something that is forbidden or not possible, but can be done if very desired.

> Если нельзя, но очень хочется, то можно

Direct translation would be
"If it is forbidden, but very desired, then it is possible".

It can be applicable for anything, like for science/technology in a good way, for people relations in a bad way (like it is forbidden to have a mistress, but if you really want you can) etc.

Is there something like this in English?

I found one by Oscar Wilde "The only way to get rid of a temptation is to yield to it", but can it be applicable not only to bad things like alcohol etc, but to science, technology?

For example, if it is well know that computer program cannot do this, but someone really did it. Can this phrase be used in that case?

Or maybe there is phrase which can be used in science/technology only. I am looking for this one (for science/technology).

Let's say (artificial example, of course) I am writing an article about possible ways to travel faster than light, or to travel to other stars, and I want to use it as an epigraph.

UPDATE1: Can I use phrase from Alice in Wonderland?
"The only way to achieve the impossible, is to believe it's possible."
but I think it is from movie, not from book.

Comment: No, the quote from Oscar  Wilde has a different meaning: he is saying that the way to get rid of something that is tempting is to fall for the temptation!! ie the cake is tempting, so just eat it! then its not tempting any more.

Comment: The quote from Alice in Wonderland conveys the idea you are referring to in your question. It is not a set phrase but it is clear.

Comment: @Josh Thanks again. Looks like I cannot use it in my case, if I understand you correctly :(

Comment: You mean that Russian has a famous figure of speech, and that you wonder if English has an equivalent?  How much fame (i.e. notority) do you require of the English version?  Would it help if you provided the ру́сский version and its cultural context?

Comment: Your original question uses the term "forbidden" - which suggests that the preventing factor is some external authority or moral code, but in your replies to answers, you use the term "impossible" - which is a different proposition ! Of course we may *think* something is "impossible" because our understanding of the problem or laws is imperfect ...

Comment: A guy I used to work with once said "We weren't smart enough to know we couldn't do it, so we did it."

Comment: I see that most answers went in the wrong direction: they seem to be about accomplishing impossible feats. The original Russian expression that OP referred to is "Если  нельзя,  но  очень хочется, то можно." It became very popular after the spy novels and the TV series in USSR, [here](http://lib.ru/RUSS_DETEKTIW/SEMENOW_YU/prikaz_v.txt)'s the link to a full text of a novel. The text (likely) incorrectly attributes the phrase to Sholom Aleichem. My English literal translation: "if something is prohibited, but you want it badly, then you go ahead and do it."

Comment: @Aksakal If most answers did go astray from the original expression, perhaps it was because OP arguably wished to extend the notion of the original to include not only "forbidden/prohibited" things but also "impossible" feats. Anyway, wouldn't impossible feats include those ["prohibited" by laws of nature](https://books.google.com/books?id=AWnDBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA187&lpg=PA187&dq=%22prohibited+by+the+laws+of+nature%22&source=bl&ots=RgulG9Bmf9&sig=2qeowwOR17aD8YYG-U616N3kNiA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiEv9fro6LSAhVC8CYKHa-ADhgQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%22prohibited%20by%20the%20laws%20of%20nature%22&f=false)?

Comment: I agree with Aksakal about original phrase, but I really want to extend it. and as I know it is used not only to something bad. I am writing an scientific article about something really impossible like traveling faster than light.

Comment: @PapaPoule it's not really extending the notion of the original - the particular Russian word already refers to both impossible things and prohibited things - possibly equivalent to "If it can't be done" that also leaves ambigious if "can't" refers to impossibility, prohibition or both.

Comment: it's possible you are looking for **"Laws were made to be broken"**.

Comment: Another one is **"Necessity is the mother of invention"**

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You may use: ***[where there's a will there's a way](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/where-there-s-a-will-there-s-a-way)***:

> - used to mean that if you are determined enough, *you can find a way to achieve what you want, even if it is very difficult*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Also:

***[will power](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/will+power):***

> - The strength of will to carry out one's decisions, wishes, or plans.

- You may say that it is only *a question of will power*  to achieve to do something.

(AHD)

Comment: This one looks good "where there's a will there's a way". But can I use it for something really impossible, like traveling with speed faster than speed of light? Let's say (artificial example of course) I am writing an article about possible ways to traveling faster than light or traveling to another stars and I want to use it as epigraph.

Comment: The saying can be applied to whatever context you like. The idea is that there is no real limit to doing or achieving something if you really are determined to do it.

Comment: @Zlelik - yes, "where there's a will there's a way" would work perfectly in that context.  You can imagine a scifi book ... *"For four hundred years, the Humes physics told them that FTL travel was impossible. But, where there's a will there's a way. And the way was the UhOhDrive - all it took was two young physicists - her lanky, him with his discrete bodybuilder's physique under the geek outfit - one late night in the laboratory with a skirt far too short and a vodka cabinet far too unlocked, and two accidents - one mathematical and one of a more personal nature..."*  That sort of thing.

Comment: As I mention above "Necessity is the mother of invention" is pretty much interchangeable with "where there's a will there's a way..."

Answer (score 28):

If "*very desired*" can be approximated to "*having faith*", you may use "***Faith will move mountains***". This also goes quite well with the alternative already considered ("*The only way to achieve the impossible, is to believe it's possible.*").

TFD(idioms):

> **[Faith will move mountains](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Faith+will+move+mountains)**.
>   *Prov*. If you believe in what you are doing, you can overcome any obstacle. (Sometimes refers to faith
>   in God.)
>   Jane's faith in her cause could move mountains.
>   You may
>   feel disheartened sometimes, but remember that faith will move
>   mountains.
>
> McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs. © 2002 by
>   The McGraw-Hill Companies, Inc.

Answer (score 24):

To use it as an [epigraph](http://softschools.com/examples/literary_terms/epigraph_examples/254/), you’d probably first have to decide whether to use [the Latin or English version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inveniam_viam) (although using both could be cool) and then whether to attribute it to [Hannibal](http://www.motivated.us/a-man-that-didnt-know-the-meaning-of-impossible/), ... [Philip Sidney](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/p/philipsidn160088.html), ... or [no one at all](http://boardofwisdom.com/togo/Quotes/ShowQuote/?msgid=501905#.WKsUkG8rLIU); but I think the notion of “not knowing the meaning of impossible” would be relevant and captured well by:

> Aut viam inveniam aut faciam:
>      I'll either find a way or make one.

(links to *softschools.com*; *Wiikipedia*; *motivated.us*; *brainyquote.com*; and *boardofwisdom.com*, respectively)

Answer (score 16):

Consider the phrase **doing the impossible**.

> **Impossible** *adjective*
>   1 Not able to occur, exist, or be done.
>   ‘An impossible dream, I told myself, but it was what I wanted.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/impossible)

Here's a similar quote:

> **Difficult is done at once, the impossible takes a little longer**, the proverbial saying, late 19th century; in the first recorded usage, Trollope's novel Phineas Redux (1873), the words are attributed to ‘a French Minister’, the French statesman Charles Alexandre de Calonne (1734–1842), who is said to have responded, ‘Madame, si c'est possible, c'est fait; impossible? cela se fera [Madam, if a thing is possible, consider it done; the impossible? that will be done].’ In modern times, the US Armed Forces have taken as their slogan, ‘The difficult we do immediately, the impossible takes a little longer.’
>   [- encyclopedia.com](http://www.encyclopedia.com/humanities/dictionaries-thesauruses-pictures-and-press-releases/difficult-done-once-impossible-takes-little-longer)

And here's an example used in the context of technology:

> The startup that's doing the impossible
>   [- TechRepublic](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/the-startup-thats-printing-missing-limbs-and-helping-paralyzed-artists-create-with-their-eyes/)

Of course, if something is truly impossible, it literally cannot be done. These sayings can be taken as a form of bravado, or they can be using *impossible* in the sense of *seemingly impossible* or perhaps *hitherto impossible*.

Answer (score 13):

In addition to Josh's answer, depending on *what it is* that fuels the desire for something difficult or forbidden, to be nonetheless done (specifically, being in dire straits or having no other resort) you could use **needs must** (or in full, **needs must when the devil drives**).

> Meaning
>
> Necessity compels. In current usage this phrase is usually used to
>   express **something that is done unwillingly but with an acceptance that
>   it can't be avoided**; for example, *I really don't want to cook tonight,
>   but needs must, I suppose*.
>
> Origin
>
> The phrase is old. In earlier texts it is almost always given in its
>   fuller form - *needs must when the devil drives*. That is, if the devil
>   is driving you, you have no choice. This dates back to Middle English
>   texts, for example Assembly of Gods, *circa* 1500:
>
> ```
> "He must nedys go that the deuell dryues."
> ```
>
> Shakespeare used the phrase several times; for example, in *All's Well
>   That Ends Well*, 1601:
>
> ```
> Countess: Tell me thy reason why thou wilt marry.
> Clown: My poor body, madam, requires it:
>        I am driven on by the flesh; and he
>        must needs go that the devil drives.
> ```

---

As quotations go, you have "They didn't know it was impossible, so they did it" by [Mark Twain](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/727021-they-did-not-know-it-was-impossible-so-they-did), or "Nothing is impossible to a willing heart" by [John Heywood](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/j/johnheywoo377091.html).

A more religious take is that [nothing is impossible to God](http://biblehub.com/matthew/19-26.htm), while a cynical person will observe that **very little is impossible to those who don't have to do it themselves**.

A somewhat different (and more ambiguous) view and quotation is supplied by [Guillaume Apollinaire](http://www.freerangekids.com/the-poem-one-principal-began-his-year-with/), *Come to the edge*, and is usually shortened in "**he pushed them, and they flew**". One way of looking at it is that if one desires it enough, he can fly, even if he was afraid and thought it impossible; so, it might be a good match for your question.

Comment: "But needs must, when the devil vomits into your kettle" - Blackadder :-)

Comment: +1 I had no idea that's where 'needs must' came from!

Comment: Always wanted to know who had said "they didn't know it was impossible, so they did it". I only knew that phrase in Portuguese, and never thought to look it up in English. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

I'm not quite sure I get your meaning, but at least when emphasizing forbidden (over impossible) the phrase that comes to my mind is ***forbidden fruit***.  This, of course, [comes from the story in Genesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forbidden_fruit) of Adam and Eve, who are directed by God not to eat the fruit of the tree of the knowledge of good and evil.  Though forbidden, they desired to eat the fruit and (coaxed by the serpent) did so.  The consequences were disastrous — at least according to traditional readings of the scripture.

To take your example of faster-than-light travel, humans in some sci-fi parable may be tempted to try it out, despite having been forbidden by physicists, with calamitous results as they detach themselves from the spacetime continuum of our cosmos.

On the other hand, [it is](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=forbidden%20fruit) also [used](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ForbiddenFruit) somewhat tongue-in-cheek to describe something that is deeply and passionately desired, but not entirely allowed on some level.  One might even argue that this is a better interpretation of the story as literature: seeing the god figure as an overbearing, petty, and selfish authority who is in many ways abusive to humans; and seeing their exile from paradise as a liberation.

If you're looking for a relevant quotation for an epigraph, I guess you could select something from [this](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0102.htm#16):

> And the LORD God commanded the man, saying: 'Of every tree of the garden thou mayest freely eat; but of the tree of the knowledge of good and evil, thou shalt not eat of it; for in the day that thou eatest thereof thou shalt surely die.'

---

Of course, I think it's pretty universally agreed that the objectively best "forbidden fruit" story is Homer Simpson's [forbidden donut](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CwSgnp_Fr9Y).  But I'm not sure that's a good fit for an epigraph.

Answer (score 6):

### if the mountain won't come to Muhammad, Muhammad must go to the mountain

> **proverb**
>   If someone won't do as you wish or a situation can't be arranged to suit you, you must accept it and change your plans accordingly.

[Oxford *Living* Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/if_the_mountain_won't_come_to_muhammad,_muhammad_must_go_to_the_mountain)

First printed in 1625, this famous proverb is said to be coined by Francis Bacon, and subsequently quoted in a book of English proverbs in 1670.

The version: *if the mountain won't come to you, you must go to the mountain* is also used. From the comments below, @Peteris tells me that the following variant is also heard

> **If Muhammad won't go to the mountain, the mountain should be brought to Muhammad**

Comment: +1 Muhammad, really? I wonder how it came to English. Was it borrowed from Arabic?

Comment: @NVZ apparently not. It might have been inspired by a Turkish proverb *Though widely associated with Muhammad, the prophet of Islam who lived in Arabia in 6th century, there is no written or oral tradition that traces this phrase back to him. There is however, a phrase in Turkish, "Dağ sana gelmezse, sen dağa gideceksin…" ("If the mountain won't come to you, you must go to the mountain") that has no reference to Muhammad, known as one of the "atasözleri", or common sayings that exist in modern Turkish, but are thought to have much older origins.* Wiktionary

Comment: But, http://www.dictionary.com/browse/if-the-mountain-won-t-come-to-muhammad--muhammad-must-go-to-the-mountain says it was indeed from the Prophet Mohammed of Islamic faith, and Arabic language.

Comment: @NVZ perfect opportunity for asking a question then.

Comment: Isn't this the opposite of what the Asker is looking for?  The question seemed to be about *not* accepting that the presence of a mountain can be a hindrance, rather than accommodating to it?

Comment: @Spagirl would you agree that it is physically impossible to move a mountain? If we want something done, if we want to achieve anything, then we have to find ways to overcome natural and manmade barriers, and find alternative measures. That is how I have always interpreted the saying.

Comment: It's also a very well-known proverb, (The OP asked for a famous phrase) which, typically, I forgot to add.

Comment: I've also heard the counterpoint proverb "If Muhammad won't go to the mountain, the mountain should be brought to Muhammad", with parallels to proverbs about literally moving mountains.

Comment: @Peteris I think I may have read that version only once or twice myself. I guess it's more common in speech than in print. Thank you for reminding me!

Answer (score 6):

I am still unclear if the task you are referring to is one that is, or is thought to be *impossible* or one that is *prohibited*.  If the latter is the case, the phrase that immediately comes to mind is:

> It is easier to beg forgiveness than it is to ask permission

This quote, or its variant:

> If it's a good idea, go ahead and do it. It is much easier to
>   apologize than it is to get permission

is attributed to [Rear Admiral Grace Hopper](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Grace_Hopper), but I do not know if she originally came up with it.

Comment: This addresses the 'forbidden' part; most other answers address the 'impossible' part.

Answer (score 5):

“They did not know it was impossible so they did it” Mark Twain.

Comment: @Hank I don't know how this answer fits. But hey, _They did not know it was **forbidden** so they did it_

Comment: @Hank The OP asked about "something that is forbidden *or not possible*" so this fits the question.

Comment: @MetaEd You are correct. I mistakenly read it as looking for something that gave off that it was both impossible and forbidden, not a phrase with just a blank to fill in either word. My mistake.

Answer (score 4):

If you're leaning more toward forbidden then you could be describing a task that is [*Taboo*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/taboo?) which could be used as:

- An Adjective: "Mount Sinai is a taboo mountain"
- A Noun: "It is taboo to climb Mount Sinai"
- A Verb: "The climbing of Mount Sinai is tabooed"

**EDIT:**

Also on the forbidden end of the spectrum: [*The Nuclear Option*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_option) is being thrown around a lot now in politics:

> The name is an analogy to nuclear weapons being the most extreme option in warfare

Answer (score 3):

### You can get it if you really want

["You Can Get It If You Really Want"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_Can_Get_It_If_You_Really_Want) is a famous reggae song written and performed by the Jamaican reggae singer songwriter Jimmy Cliff, a famous version of which was later recorded by Desmond Dekker.

The [lyrics](https://play.google.com/music/preview/Tv7apfckni4446p3uhccgspypha?lyrics=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=lyrics&pcampaignid=kp-songlyrics) inform the meaning:

> You can get it if you really want 
>   You can get it if you really want 
>  
>   You can get it if you really want 
>  
>   But you must try, try and try, try and try 
>  
>   You'll succeed at last, mmh, yeah
>
> Persecution you must fear
>  
>   Win or lose you're about to get your share
>  
>   Got your mind set on a dream
>  
>   You can get it though hard it may seem now
>
> You can get it if you really want...
>
> Listen, Rome was not built in a day
>  
>   Opposition will come your way 
>   But the harder the battle, you see
>  
>   Is the sweeter the victory now
>
> You can get it if you really want...

Answer (score 2):

The phrase you are looking for is "Anything is possible if you want it badly enough".

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Comment: Sorry.

The phrase is common and means more or less what NVZ was looking for.

**Anything** is possible, even things usually deemed **impossible** if the person trying to achieve it has sufficient desire.

So to break it down, impossible becomes possible with sufficient desire.

This more or less matches the original russian phrase quoted in the question: "If it is forbidden, but very desired, then it is possible". Again, impossible becomes possible with sufficient desire.

Comment: Information needs to be added to the answer, not the comments.

Comment: This will be a great answer if expanded on.

Answer (score 2):

> People saying: “It can’t be done,” are always being interrupted by somebody doing it.

Origins are murky, but explored [here.](http://quoteinvestigator.com/2015/01/26/doing/) Possibly *Puck Magazine*.

Answer (score 1):

**Rising to the challenge**: [If someone rises to the challenge, they act in response to a difficult situation which is new to them and are successful.](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-rise-to-the-challenge)